# Why PHP cannot execute the echo "<?"?

Tags: php

Can some of you tell me please why when I echo `"<?"`, the `<?` is not displayed?

I'm sorry, maybe it's very stupid question, but I need to dig this language more deeper.

Comment: "not displayed"? I don't think so, try View Source in chrome, you'll see it's there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you view the source it will be there. Its because the browser thinks its a tag.

Fix it by using [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
echo htmlentities("<?");
```